# Opera doesn't recognize body css classes

Tags: html, css, opera

cep  I have an odd problem.  I am building a site in which there are classes in the HTML body tag.  All other browsers do as expected.  However, Opera simple won't recognize these classes.  In the source code, even in Opera, they are there.  But when I look with "Inspect Element", the only class body has is "yui-sam-skin".  I'm using Wordpress so the template is "`<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

However, I've even tried `<body class="<?php if(is_front_page() ) echo "home"; ?>">`.  Again, all browsers expect Opera recognize it and Opera has it in the source code, but not in Inspect Element.  Any idea what's happening here?  This doesn't happen with every site.  A site I built not long ago doesn't have this problem for some reason.  Even adding in the class with no PHP at all doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show us the CSS code and the HTML output. Opera usually *does* recognize classes on body.

Comment: Do you know where the `yui-sam-skin` class is coming from? It could be that a script is running that is updating the body class and overwriting what is already there and for some reason is only doing it in opera (a misguided browser fix of some kind maybe?)...

Comment: it's working on my opera 11.50

Comment: Really?  The Inspect Element reads <body class="home">?  Also, the Home title of the page shows up if the class isn't present.  It disappears when the class is working as expected. Also, the slider should go across the width of the page, not just half of it.

Comment: Well, I guess I could try reinstalling Opera then...

Comment: I'll share a printscreen with you wait

Comment: http://s11.postimage.org/s69e0jx1f/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your source code, you seem to have TWO body elements in your markup...one with a class of home, the other one with the yui class. Opera Dragonfly's inspection tool shows the actual DOM representation, after the browser's parser has sanitised your broken markup. view source and look for "body" and you'll see the problem. or, run the page through a validator. i'd suggest fixing that in the first instance.

Comment: Huh.  You're right.  It looks like it's GoDaddy's preview DNS.  The site isn't actually live yet, it's just a temporary thing on GoDaddy.  The code below the extra body div looks like it relates to that.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to pretend its fine on Opera until I actually take it live and GoDaddy removes the Preview code.